# Run Bun on Windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, create-react-app, bun

Bun has been on every news aggregator and newsletter related to tech the past week due to its speed compared to create-react-app .
I've tried to run it on Windows, but seems it is not supported yet. Does anyone know if they can run it on Windows?

Comment: Note that if you want a faster alternative to create-react-app, you'd likely be better off with Vite for now. It can also be run in Bun, though it doesn't fully take advantage of Bun yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Installation docs](https://bun.sh/docs/installation#windows):

> Bun provides a *limited, experimental* native build for Windows. At the
> moment, only the Bun runtime is supported.
>
> - `bun <file>`
> - `bun run <file>`
>
> The test runner, package manager, and bundler are still under
> development. The following commands have been disabled.
>
> - `bun test`
> - `bun install/add/remove`
> - `bun link/unlink`
> - `bun build`

Alternatively if you need those commands or an older version of Bun, you can use [Windows Subsystem Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl):

```
wsl --install
wsl curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
wsl bun
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Can I run it on VS Code or do I need to install ubuntu?

Comment: You would need to install a distribution like Ubuntu in the Microsoft store. You don’t need to install the operating system manually though. VSCode can also use WSL.

Comment: While I think this answer is generally the way to go. `wsl` and then `bun` works. However I'm not getting `wsl bun` to work from powershell, because of `/bin/bash: bun: command not found`. It seems that this is because `~/.bashrc` is never `source`d in PS. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't installed Bun. I've updated my answer to include installation instructions for WSL and information on the new native Windows build.